# how to use bitsadmin.exe (Windows) download file from authenticated Jenkins server

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am aware of using following command to download files from Jenkins server if the workspace is anonymous access:

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer replica /priority FOREGROUND http://1.1.1.1:8080/job/dump_data/ws/dump_data.zip %WORKSPACE%\dump_data.zip
```

But what if the Jenkins server is authenticated by username/password ?

EDIT: /setcredentials works, but one problem is that I can only use /create, /addfile, /resume, then /complete. How can I wait till transfer finish then continue the batch script?

EDIT:
Further test shows /setcredential didn't work. The previous test shows it works because my Jenkins allow anonymous access at that time. 
I captured the packet when using the bitadmin. It shows http request is HEAD without any credential information.
If I use curl-win to download, the http request is GET  with basic authentication username and password.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to set credentials on a BITS job, you'd use the `/setcredentials` switch.

```
 /SETCREDENTIALS job target scheme username password
     Adds credentials to a job.
     target may be either SERVER or PROXY
     scheme may be BASIC, DIGEST, NTLM, NEGOTIATE, or PASSPORT.
```

[The excellent ss64 command reference for BITSadmin can be found here](http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html).

Comment: This works, but one problem is that I can only use /create, /addfile, /resume, then /complete. How can I wait till transfer finish then continue the batch script?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `.bat` script corresponding to the question:

```
bitsadmin /Create DownloadDumpData
bitsadmin /SetCredentials DownloadDumpData target scheme username password
bitsadmin /AddFile DownloadDumpData http://1.1.1.1:8080/job/dump_data/ws/dump_data.zip %WORKSPACE%\dump_data.zip
bitsadmin /SetPriority DownloadDumpData "FOREGROUND"
bitsadmin /Resume DownloadDumpData
:WAIT_DUMP_DATA_DOWNLOAD_LOOP_START
    @rem state thanks to http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html & http://serverfault.com/a/646948/93281
    call bitsadmin /info DownloadDumpData /verbose | find "STATE: TRANSFERRED"
    if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 goto WAIT_DUMP_DATA_DOWNLOAD_LOOP_END
    call bitsadmin /RawReturn /GetBytesTransferred DownloadDumpData
    @rem sleep thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1672375/535203
    timeout 2
    goto WAIT_DUMP_DATA_DOWNLOAD_LOOP_START
:WAIT_DUMP_DATA_DOWNLOAD_LOOP_END
call bitsadmin /Complete DownloadDumpData
```

Comment: At least in Windows 10, `/transfer` (with optional `/rawreturn`) downloads synchronously.